# get product attribute by product attribute group in magento 2

Tags: magento2

how to get product **attribute  group** in magento 2 from a **attribute set**.
I want to show attribute on **listing page** by using a group so i can add more attributes in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you simply get all product attribute by `$product->getAttributes();`

```
$productAttributes=$product->getAttributes();
        $group_id=9;
        $attributeSetId=4;
        foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->isInGroup($attributeSetId, $group_id)) {
             echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel().' : '.$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product).'<br />';
            }

    }
```

Comment: how would I get the group_id if I do not know it, from the product detail page?

Comment: @IamFace follow https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-get-product-attributes-attribute-groups/

Answer (score 2):

you can get all the attributes as below:

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
     $attribute->getCode();
}
```

Ref. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98945/magento-2-how-can-i-get-all-product-attributes-and-get-the-value-yes-no

Answer (score 1):

To get the groupId,

```
//groupCollection - Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory object


$groupCollection = $this->_groupCollection->create();
$groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId);        $groupCollection>addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name','sample_group_name');
$firstItem = $groupCollection->getFirstItem();
echo $firstItem->getData('attribute_group_id');
```